# How should I understand 追加で in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> ドル札を追加で用意してくる

Should I understand 追加で as noun + で particle to mean additionally in an adverbial way or should I understand it as another form of the verb form 追加して? I recalled seeing it used this way before where the speaker just says を + verb but instead of fulling turning it into verbs by adding する they just say the verb root + だ or で. Is my observation correct and what is it in this case?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "de-form of a suru-verb." This 追加 is a simple noun meaning *extra/addition*, and this で is a case particle to mark a condition/scope.

Similar examples of `noun + で` include 合計で ("in total"), 割引で ("at a discount price"), 確認で ("for conformation"), 一人で ("alone"), 土足で ("with one's shoes on"), 本気で ("seriously"), 笑顔で ("with a smile"), etc. All of these work adverbially.